# Replace parent component's element in child component in Angular

Tags: angular

It it possible in Angular 8 to replace parent component's HTML element? Like this:

```html
<!-- app.component.html -->
<div id=555>?</div>
```

```html
<!-- components/my/my.component.html -->
<div replacementForId=555>overriden from a child component</div>
```

A more complex interactive HTML supposed to be there, not a simple string. I'd like to keep the parent unaware about what is in that div.

Comment: have you tried `@Input`

Comment: mean you want what ever data inside in this `<div id=555>?</div>`

Comment: You should use @Output in child component and handle the event in parent component: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-output-example

Comment: With `@Output` I can pass a value, but how can I pass en interactive element?